# OpenCV Symbols loaded and cannot open PDB file error

Tags: opencv, fingerprint, feature-extraction

I am implementing the program for extracting the minutiae points .

I had tried some sample codes from the openCV library, it has worked but now it is giving the error.

More Info:
1) I am working on 64 bit architecture but I have used 32 bit opencv settings.

2) Made changes accordingly in the property sheet file.

Errors:

```
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\jaythegenius48\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded  'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_core249.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_highgui249.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Please if someone can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

that's not an error, just a warning.

the pdb files are not supplied with the prebuild binaries (matter of size), so you can't debug the opencv src code.

if you really need that feature, run cmake, and rebuild the libs locally.

Comment: Thank you @berak Even though it was an error, it was not running. What should I do?

Comment: "It was not running" - there might be complete different reasons for that, i.e most of the example progs expect cmdline args, like an image-path, and just stop if you did not give it any.

Comment: I made some changes in command arguments in my project, by supplying image file. Still can't get the desired result.It was simple histogram file given in the samples of openCV folder.

Comment: start a new question with the exact program, and the exact error. sentences like "but it does not work" don't help anyone.